# Find substrings that start and end with same Uppercase Character

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have a homework problem where I need to use regex to parse substrings out of a large string.

The goal is to select substrings that match the following parameters:

Substring starts and ends with the same uppercase character, and I need to ignore any instances of uppercase characters with the number 0 in front of them.

For example, `ZAp0ZuZAuX0AZA` would contain the matches `ZAp0ZuZ` and `AuX0AZA`

I've been messing around with this for a few hours and honestly haven't even gotten close...

I've tried some stuff like the code below, but that will select everything from the first uppercase through the last uppercase. I've also

```py
[A-Z]{1}[[:alnum:]]*[A-Z]{1} <--- this selects the whole string
[A-Z]{1}[[:alnum:]][A-Z]{1} <--- this gives me strings like ZuZ, AuX
```

Really appreciate any help, I'm totally stumped on this one.

Comment: Hello! Would you kindly share your attempts -- of any degree? This way, we can ensure we're not pulling the chestnuts out of the fire for you.

Comment: I am not sure what you are doing, but this is not python. Python characterclasses are written differently.

Comment: @MegaIng `[[:alnum:]]`  is supported by the PyPi regex module, but Ryan has not provided any regex library details.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: Ryan, please check my answer and let know if you need more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
(?<!0)([A-Z]).*?(?<!0)\1
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jd8WQG/3).

**Details**

- `(?<!0)([A-Z])` - Group 1: an ASCII uppercase letter not preceded with a zero
- `.*?` - any char but a linebreak char as few as possible
- `(?<!0)\1` - the same letter as in Group 1 not immediately preceded with `0`.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xkNHe1):

```
import re
s="ZAp0ZuZAuX0AZA"
for m in re.finditer(r'(?<!0)([A-Z]).*?(?<!0)\1', s):
    print(m.group()) # => ['ZAp0ZuZ', 'AuX0AZA']
```

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best idea to do that with regular expressions, since simply you could split them. However, if you have/wish to do so, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/Fy18VE/1) might give you an idea what problems you might be facing, when your char list expands:

```
(?=.[A-Z])([A-Z])(.*?)\1
```

I have added `(?=.[A-Z])` that must contain one uppercase. You can remove it and it would work. You can however add such boundaries to your expressions for safety.

[image]

[image]

#### JavaScript Test

```js
const regex = /([A-Z])(.*?)\1/gm;
const str = `ZAp0ZuZAuX0AZA
ZApxxZuZAuXxafaAZA
ZApxaf09xZuZAuX090xafaAZA
abcZApxaf09xZuZAuX090xafaAZA`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Python Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([A-Z])(.*?)\1"

test_str = ("ZAp0ZuZAuX0AZA\n"
    "ZApxxZuZAuXxafaAZA\n"
    "ZApxaf09xZuZAuX090xafaAZA\n"
    "abcZApxaf09xZuZAuX090xafaAZA")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    
    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))
    
    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1
        
        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work

`(?<!0)([A-Z]).*?(?<!0)\1`

https://regex101.com/r/nES9FP/1

Explained

```
 (?<! 0 )      # Ignore Upper case with zero in front of it
 ( [A-Z] )     # (1), This Upper case is to be found down stream
 .*?           # Lazy, any character
 (?<! 0 )      # Ignore Upper case with zero in front of it
 \1            # Backref to what is in group (1)
```